# dynamically add a link button in gridview template field at run time together a label control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface

I have a gridview in my form. I am working with `RowDataBound` event to the grid. Now I have a template field inside columns of the gridview. A label has been taken inside template field. I want to add a link to this label on `RowDataBound` event at runtime, but `.System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton`  is showing instead of link button.
How do I add a link button with label text in the grid view?

Comment: I think you may need to Add custom Attribute to your Label control. Please search something like "Adding Custom Attribute in Runtime" and hope you may find a way out. Also please try something by yourself so that you can decide what to do and what not. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a linkbutton inside your templatefield

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridView">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkTest"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Then in your rowdatabound event you can find it and do whatever you want

```
void gridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Entity entity = e.Row.DataItem as Entity;

            LinkButton lnkTest = e.Row.FindControl("lnkTest") as LinkButton;
            lnkTest.CommandArgument = entity.ID.ToString();
            lnkTest.Text = entity.Name;
        }
    }
```

You can then subscribe to gridview Command event and correct CommandArgument will be passed when clicking by linkbutton.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Initially there is a label inside item template. but i want add a link button by replacing this label on some conditions . not all linkbutton.link button should be display if any condition is to be true.

Comment: Didn't you want to change your ItemTemplate, so it will contain both label and linkbutton and you will change visibility on rowdatabound depending on your conditions?
Also it would be helpful if you edit your original post and add piece of your markup and code so it will be clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ya sir/mam this is the solution of my ques. Thanks a lot Sir/Mam

Comment: <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridView">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTest"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkTest" visible="false"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>